# problems in member function

Tags: c++, string, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class student {
    int roll_no;
    char name[56];

public:
    void setdata(int roll_no_in, const char* name_in) {
        roll_no = roll_no_in;
        strcpy(name, name_in);
    }

    void outdata() {
        cout << "rollno is " << roll_no << endl << "name is " << name << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    student s1;
    s1.setdata(12, "robin");
    s1.outdata();
    return 0;
}
```

i have some doubts in this program

1. how can we store strings into pointer like above program storing the string robin into char *name_in  since pointers are used only to store address.Can we store even strings?
2. why should i add `const` in the method function set data if i don't use
   that then it  shows me error. It is optional right?
3. why can't i use `char name_in[34]` in the place of `char *name_in` in the `setdata` method function?

Comment: _"i have some doubts in this program"_ I also have some. Why don't you use `std::string name;` in 1st place?

Comment: then strcpy dosent accept string variables

Comment: You don't need `strcpy()` for `std::string`, it provides an [assignment `operator=()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D)

Answer (score 1):

1. C strings are arrays of `char`. When you pass an array as a function argument, it's converted to a pointer to the first element.
2. The `const` modifier indicates that the function will not modify the contents of `name_in`. Since string literals are constants, you need this to permit the function to be called with a literal argument.
3. You can. But since the function doesn't actually have a limit on the size of the string it will accept, that would be misleading. Declaring a parameter as an array with a length is treated just like declaring it as a pointer; the length you specify is ignored. **Note**: This is only true for the first dimension; when passing a multi-dimensional array, you can omit the first dimension's length, but need to specify all the other dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

> how can we store strings into pointer like above program storing the string johnson into `char *name_in` since pointers are used only to store address.

You're not storing it in `name_in`, you're storing it into `name`, which is an array. `name_in` is a pointer to the array passed to the function; the array is automatically converted to a pointer when passed to a function. (More generally, a pointer can point to the start of an array, and be used to access the array; C-style functions like `strcpy` do exactly that.)

In idiomatic C++, you'd use a class rather than this dangerous mucking about with pointers and arrays:

```
std::string name;
name = name_in;
```

> why should i add const in the method function set data if i dont use that then it shows me error.

I assume you mean in `const char * name_in`. You're passing a pointer to a string literal, which is constant; and the language doesn't allow you to take a non-constant pointer to a constant object.

> It is optional right?

Before C++11, it was optional; leaving it out was merely a very bad idea. Now it's mandatory.

> why can't i use `char name_in[34]` in the place of `char *name_in` in the setdata method function

You can; as a function argument, both are equivalent. Again you'll need `const` to be able to pass a string literal or other constant string. It would be somewhat misleading though, implying that `name_in` is an array, of a particular size, when neither are guaranteed.

Again, this is C++, so `std::string` is almost certainly a better option than either.

Answer (score 0):

*how can we store strings into pointer like above program storing the string johnson into char *name_in since pointers are used only to store address.Can we store even strings?*

You are actually storing pointer to the base address of the string. You can use this pointer to traverse whole string.

*why should i add const in the method function set data if i dont use that then it shows me error*

"Ravi" is a string literal which is stored in memory which is read only. So, if you try to pass this literal to function accepting `char *`, it would be the violation of the constraint compiler is trying to establish.

*why can't i use char name_in[34] in the place of char *name_in in the setdata method function?*

You are passing pointer to char to this function, so you have to use pointer to char to accept it. However, arrays , when passed to function as argument decays to a pointer.